# Azure Logic app is failing when Null values in previous step

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am having issue with logic app executing a query and that query returning the null value some times so, I have added null check but still I am getting the error, can any one help me on this?

```
My null check coalesce(body('Run_query_and_list_results_2')?['value'],'')
```

Check images[image]

[image]

Comment: you can try checking the length as length(body('Run_query_and_list_results_2')?['value']) = 0 or "equals":[  
               "@empty(body('Run_query_and_list_results_2')?['value'])",
               true
            ]

Comment: Thank you one more thing is i am looping through result set but my result set is having 1 million records and Logic app is not working because of limitation what should be the best way to do that ?

Comment: You can setup a pagination as described here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure#process-data-in-bulk

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40060.sql-pagination-for-bulk-data-transfer-with-logic-apps.aspx

Comment: Btw just checking , did my first comment worked out for you  ?

Comment: Yes it worked , what is the best approach will it be the SQL pagination or queue? SQL pagination again there is a loop so

Comment: I have never tried that so cant say what to choose but I would suggest to keep performance and manageability in mind while choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try checking the length as

```
length(body('Run_query_and_list_results_2')?['value']) = 0
```

or using equals operator as

```
"equals":[ "@empty(body('Run_query_and_list_results_2')?['value'])", true ]
```